# Exception raised file_path function in Scrapy Pipeline not showed

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

So, I put a simple exception in an image pipeline like this:

```
class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    #Name download version
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        raise Exception()
        print("It get's into filepath")
```

It should have shown an error, but it just makes the whole pipeline doesn't work. Even the print does not get printed. How can I trace that error?

I can trace it in other functions but not in file_path.

Comment: Why not use a logger and log an error instead of raising an exception?